# Google API issue: google image search

Tags: ios, iphone, google-image-search

I want to enter keyword and get proper images from google according to these keywords. For instance, I enter "pencil" and want to get first 100 images of pencil from google images.

The best way I found is to make GET request of https://www.google.com/search?q=pencil&tbm=isch, parse html page, get urls of images, and load images by these urls.

1. Is there any better way to load images according to the keyword?
2. Will I get ban from google if my application loads images that way?

Comment: You might want to look at Google [Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

Comment: They have a limit: up to 100 queries a day. Is that limit for all users of my application? or each of my users can make up to 100 queries?

Comment: I believe it's per user, but I certainly can't guarantee anything -- you'll probably need to sort that out with Google.

Comment: Do you know url of google support of developers where I can ask this question?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, please use json. Read here for detail and sample https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

2) It seems google doesn't allow that way (I can't remember where in TOS) but I don't know if they will ban your app or not.